# How do we add a column to resultset to show count in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running the following query on PostgreSQL DB to get the status of each channel on different dates.

```
SELECT ch.name,
   date(msg.date_created),
   msg.status
FROM message msg,
 channel ch
WHERE msg.status !='TRANSFORMED'
AND msg.channel_id = ch.id
AND msg.date_created BETWEEN to_date('2015-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('2015-01-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

It fetches the data in the following format :

```
Channel_Name,Date,Status
CHANNEL_01,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_04,1/10/2015,QUEUED
CHANNEL_02,1/10/2015,QUEUED
CHANNEL_02,1/10/2015,FILTERED
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,QUEUED
CHANNEL_02,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_01,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,ERROR
CHANNEL_01,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,ERROR
CHANNEL_04,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,FILTERED
CHANNEL_04,1/10/2015,ERROR
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,ERROR
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,SENT
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,FILTERED
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,QUEUED
CHANNEL_04,1/10/2015,FILTERED
```

But I want count the status of message and display in a column grouped by name and date. How should I rewrite the query with "group by" to achieve the expected result as follows?

```
Channel_Name,Date,SENT,QUEUED,ERROR,FILTERED
CHANNEL_01,1/10/2015,3,0,0,0
CHANNEL_02,1/10/2015,1,0,0,1
CHANNEL_02,1/11/2015,0,1,0,0
CHANNEL_03,1/10/2015,3,2,1,2
CHANNEL_03,1/11/2015,1,0,2,0
CHANNEL_04,1/10/2015,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SUM(CASE)`, repeat this construction for each status value:

```
SELECT ch.name,
   date(msg.date_created),
   SUM(CASE WHEN msg.status = 'SENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SENT,
   ... -- same for other statuses
FROM message msg,
 channel ch
WHERE msg.status !='TRANSFORMED'
AND msg.channel_id = ch.id
AND msg.date_created BETWEEN to_date('2015-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('2015-01-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY ch.name, date(msg.date_created);
```

Comment: ... or use `COUNT(CASE WHEN msg.status = 'SENT' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as SENT'

Answer (score 1):

As an intermediate step, you can `GROUP BY ch.name, date(msg.date_created), msg.status` and count the number of msgs per status for each channel name and date, like so:

```
SELECT ch.name,
   date(msg.date_created),
   msg.status,
   COUNT(*)
FROM message msg,
 channel ch
WHERE msg.status !='TRANSFORMED'
AND msg.channel_id = ch.id
AND msg.date_created BETWEEN to_date('2015-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('2015-01-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY ch.name, date(msg.date_created), msg.status;
```

This should give you an output of the form:

```
CHANNEL_01,1/10/2015,SENT,3
CHANNEL_02,1/10/2015,QUEUED,1
CHANNEL_02,1/11/2015,ERROR,1
```

which is just a few steps from the final desired result.

Comment: The only way I'm seeing to transform my output into what you asked for is a query with 4 nested subqueries for each of the 4 status types.

Comment: I am really feeling lucky.